# How the 'new' operator is handled in bind()?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning `.call()`, `.apply()`, `.bind()` methods in JavaScript. When it comes to `bind()` method, I came across one line:

> Please note that the value for the first parameter is ignored if the bound function is constructed using the "new" operator.

Which I don't understand. What does it mean to *construct a bound function using the `new` operator*?

Comment: You can check the bind example by `Omer Goldberg` at https://medium.com/@omergoldberg/javascript-call-apply-and-bind-e5c27301f7bb

Comment: `function F () { console.log(this); }; let G = F.bind({ key: 'value' });` compare `new G()` to `G()`

Answer (score 2):

So let's break this down. First of all, what does the "new" keyword do? Among other things, it calls the function in front of it but with the value of "this" set to a newly created empty object.
This is useful in making new instances of an object using a constructor function. (I'd suggest you read more into it)

Now the .bind method on the other hand will create a copy of the function it is called on, but with the value of "this" set to the first argument you pass into it.

Therefore, this just means that if you use new to try to call a function which is bound with a value for the "this" keyword, the "new" keyword will override your .bind and "this" will be set to an empty object.

As I said, "new" is used to make new instances using a function that "constructs" that instance. So using "new" to construct a bound function means using a bound function as a constructor.